# Can php a href post not use a link like index.php?id=value

Tags: php, post

I want to post some value through a href. However, I do not like to use a link like `index.php?id=value`. Is there any other method?

I want to post `test1` and `test2`.

```
<div id="div1">
  <li><a href="index.php">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php">test2</a></li>
</div>
<div id="div2">this is a <? $_POST["name"]; ?>, just a test.</div>
```

Comment: perhaps you can tell us what you want the link to look like

Comment: the page's url has no change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a form, with method=POST, and a hidden form field for the value you want to post.  The 'href' either becomes a submit button, or have an onclick action on the link that just submits the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can apparently use PHP for this, and the information is supposed to be here, but it is currently not working:

http://www.zend.com/zend/spotlight/mimocsumissions.php

Otherwise, you should probably just do this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="index.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="value">
  <input type="hidden" name="somethingElse" value="test">
  <!-- more stuff you want to post -->
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="myForm.submit()">Post!</a>
```

The form is invisible, but you need one form per link like this (or I guess you could use only 1 form total and call another javascript function from the onclick event that modifies the values of the form fields). I don't really see the benefit though.

Comment: <form id="myForm" method="post" action="index.php"> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="value"> <input type="hidden" name="name" value="test"> <!-- more stuff you want to post --> </form> <a href="#" onclick="myForm.submit()">Post!</a> <div id="div2">this is a <? $_POST["name"]; ?>, just a test.</div>

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your PHP is wrong. You're not echoing/printing the variable. Replace the PHP code by this: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You could use either jQuery/ajax to post your data to a backend or post the variables as said in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite (if you are using Apache) to modify the look of url. e.g. instead of www.test.com/index.php?id=value you can use www.test.com/value or www.test.com/index/value